# On which way does RDD of spark finish fault-tolerance?

Tags: apache-spark

Spark revolves around the concept of a resilient distributed dataset (RDD), which is a fault-tolerant collection of elements that can be operated on in parallel. But, I did not find the internal mechanism on which the RDD finish fault-tolerance. Could somebody describe this mechanism？Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let me explain in very simple terms as I understand.

Faults in a cluster can happen when one of the nodes processing data is crashed. In spark terms, RDD is split into partitions and each node (called the `executors`) is operating on a partition at any point of time. (Theoretically, each each executor can be assigned multiple tasks depending on the number of cores assigned to the job versus the number of partitions present in the RDD).

By operation, what is really happening is a series of Scala functions (called transformations and actions in Spark terms depending on if the function is pure or side-effecting) executing on a partition of the RDD. These operations are composed together and Spark execution engine views these as a Directed Acyclic Graph of operations.

Now, if a particular node crashes in the middle of an operation Z, which depended on operation Y, which inturn on operation X. The cluster manager (YARN/Mesos) finds out the node is dead and tries to assign another node to continue processing. This node will be told to operate on the particular partition of the RDD and the series of operations X->Y->Z (called `lineage`) that it has to execute, by passing in the Scala closures created from the application code. Now the new node can happily continue processing and there is effectively no data-loss.

Spark also uses this mechanism to guarantee `exactly-once` processing, with the caveat that any side-effecting operation that you do like calling a database in a Spark `Action` block can be invoked multiple times. But if you view your transformations like pure functional mapping from one RDD to another, then you can be rest assured that the resulting RDD will have the elements from the source RDD processed only once.

The domain of fault-tolerance in Spark is very vast and it needs much bigger explanation. I am hoping to see others coming up with technical details on how this is implemented, etc. Thanks for the great topic though.

Comment: Agree that cluster manager will take care of failure. But 1 executor per partition is it true?means suppose i have 2000 partitions then i will have 2000 executors for parallel processing?is it always the case ?

Comment: 1 executor work on one partition at a time,when it finished, this executor will be idle. If there are still partitions that have not been executed,driver will schedule task to this idle executor.That means, one executor can work on many partitions

Comment: To to accurate, It is not Yarn but Driver 's responsibility to reschedule the failed task to another executor.

Comment: Yarn's responsibility is to re-launch the executor in a container and drivers responsibility is to re-launch the failed tasks on that executor.